# Browser gem testing with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I am using the gem [Browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser)
to detect mobile devices and redirect them to a different landing on a rails app. The code I'm using is this one :

```
Rails.configuration.middleware.use Browser::Middleware do
  redirect_to mobile_landing_path if browser.device.mobile? || browser.device.ipad? || browser.device.tablet?
end
```

Now I need to do a feature test using Rspec and capybara, and I'm a little lost here. Really appreciate the help .

Tests I have right now is using [capybara user agent](https://github.com/mururu/capybara-user_agent/blob/master/README.md) and looks like this: but it seems it stills gets the base landing and not the mobile one

```
feature 'Visiting the site from an' do
 context 'Android device' do
  background do
   set_user_agent(:android)
  end

  scenario 'I should be redirected to mobile landing' do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_current_path(mobile_landing_path)
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test, what have you tried, what errors did you get? (also your logic seems backwards -- I would think you want to redirect to the mobile_landing_path if the browser is mobile?)

Comment: I've corrected the logic and added the test I'm trying to tackle

Comment: Are you sure Browser and Capybara-user_agent define "Android" as explicitly mobile? Have you tried specifically setting the test to other mobile agents (like iOS) and testing to see if that works?

Comment: The same result, but thanks

Comment: What is your definition of set_user_agent? Also don't use eq with current_path it'll cause you headaches when you use JS enabled drivers, instead get used to using the have_current_path matcher - `expect(page).to have_current_path(mobile_landing_path)`

Comment: set_user_agent comes from the gem capybara user agent and comes with some predefined user agents as iphone, android, etc you just supose to add this : 
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::UserAgent::DSL
end 
on the config

Comment: Browser only runs its middleware if the HTTP_ACCEPT header matches %r[(text/html|\*/\*)]  - I'm guessing its not set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser gem middleware will only be run when the HTTP_ACCEPT header is set and matches %r[(text/html|*/*)] . By default the rack-test driver doesn't set any headers. You can either overwrite the provided driver registration like

```
Capybara.register_driver :rack_test do |app|
  Capybara::RackTest::Driver.new(app, :headers => { 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html' })
end
```

or you can create a new driver registration

```
Capybara.register_driver :rack_test_with_html_accept do |app|
  Capybara::RackTest::Driver.new(app, :headers => { 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html' })
end
```

and then add `driver: :rack_test_with_html_accept` metadata to your tests that need that header to be set

```
feature 'Visiting the site from an', driver: :rack_test_with_html_accept do
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks sir, you make my day

Comment: just as a simple comment is preferred to use new syntax for this:
Capybara::RackTest::Driver.new(app, headers: { 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html' })
But the answer was really well made, thanks @TomWalpole